# Android AsyncTasks Not Running in Google Play Deployment but working normal when launched to device from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask, google-play-console, android-developer-api

I have been developing Android for 13 years and today I discovered the first issue I am completely not able to understand or even begin to debug.

My app which makes a number of web calls to fetch data is able to deploy to my test devices and run normally, however after uploading to the Google Play store and downloading it to make sure everything is working as expected I realized that my app doesn't load at all, it doesn't crash or give any errors, after looking at some log messages from my app that is in the play store I have been able to conclude that none of my AsyncTasks that make web calls are running, hence why my app does not load, of all the insane things I have been through with android this is a borderline nightmare to experience as none of those issues occurred in testing.

What is even more insane is I have one AsyncTask that does not make a web call and it seems to execute normally, so the issue seems to be that the AsyncTasks making web calls never execute the doin background phase because no logs ever run from those methods after the class is called.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Because there is no error code or warning the only relevant data I can give is:

```
compileSdkVersion 32
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 32
```

I had to update my app compile and target versions, my android studio amongst other things to be able to upload to the play store, other than that I have no way to figure out what is wrong or how to fix it

Comment: have you tried disabling minifying or excluding these Asyncs from minify?